# Include JQuery in an injected script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome app composed of:

- a window containing a webview.
- a background script that injects a script into the webview.

I need to use JQuery in the injected script.
Where do I have to include JQuery? I included it in window.html and it works using the console but it doesn't work for the webview's script.

Comment: By "injected script" you mean the context created by `webview.executeScript`? Adding your code may help here.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

This might achieve what you want, although I've not tested it with webview I used it with chrome.tabs.executeScript.

```
webview.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    webview.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
});
```